# Greasemonkey AJAX post does not appear to work, even with @grant specified

Tags: javascript, http-post, greasemonkey, gm-xmlhttprequest

My script does not work. The AJAX call is not happening. Why?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        prova
// @namespace   http://blogpagliaccio.wordpress.com/
// @description prova
// @include     http://*
// @version     1
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @require     http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/85398.user.js
// ==/UserScript==

// [........... other code]

    console.log('start ajax call...');
            GM_xmlhttpRequest({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "www.prova.it",
                    data: {parametro:parametro},
                    onload: function(response) {
                            console.log(response.responseText);
                    },
                    onerror: function(reponse) {
                            alert('error');
                            console.log(reponse);
                    }
            });
```

I listed the API function in a `@grant` directive, but I do not see an AJAX call and response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [the documents for `GM_xmlhttpRequest()`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest#Arguments).  `data` takes only a **string**.

If you try to send non-string data to `data`, you will get an error like:

> Component does not have requested interface
>   (113 out of range 67)

So, you must encode data into an appropriate string. Also, you will need to send the appropriate `Content-Type` header.  The two main types/methods are:

1. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
   And
2. `application/json`

Encoding and sending the data looks like this for the two methods:

**Form-encoded data:**

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method:     "POST",
    url:        "www.prova.it",
    data:       "parametro=" + encodeURIComponent (parametro),
    headers:    {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    onload:     function (response) {
        console.log(response.responseText);
    },
    onerror:    function(reponse) {
        //alert('error');
        console.log("error: ", reponse);
    }
} );
```

**JSON serialized data:**

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method:     "POST",
    url:        "www.prova.it",
    data:       JSON.stringify ( {parametro:parametro} ),
    headers:    {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    onload:     function (response) {
        console.log(response.responseText);
    },
    onerror:    function(reponse) {
        //alert('error');
        console.log("error: ", reponse);
    }
} );
```